# Fetch private repos via access_token from github api?

Tags: javascript, fetch, github-api

I want all public and private repos of a user. So I first authenticate that user using basic OAUTH while authenticating I am also adding "REPO" scope. So as per api documentation I shoud get all repos using that token but I am getting only public ones. Can any one give me an example using JAVASCRIPT fetch method to get user private repos using access_token ?